# How do I automate this date code so I don't have to change it every year?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

How do I automate this date code so I don't have to change it every year?

```
where (Load_Date) >= #12/01/2018#
```

I need dates greater than or equal to Dec of last year.

For example in 2019 I need dates of Dec 2018 and greater. In 2020 I will need dates of Dec 2019 and greater.

Answer (score 5):

Never use string handling for dates in VBA when it can be avoided.

```
where Load_Date >= DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, 12, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can do this.  I don't have access to test, but it works in VBA:

```
where (Load_Date) >= "12/01/" & Year(date())-1
```

Comment: Use `DateSerial` to generate dates, otherwise this will not work in different localizations. Never use strings when handling dates (unless for displaying purpose).

Comment: This will result in dates greater than 12. January  in many localizations. Also, afaik, in most localizations `/` is not an acceptable date-delimiter.